# Ошибка при сборке deb-пакета

Tags: c++, cmake, deb, travis-ci

Есть проект. В нем есть сабмодули, различные библиотеки и подпроекты. Один из таких подпроектов - сервер. Хочу, чтобы тревис собирал его не только в исполняемый фаил, но и в deb-пакет. Для этого в cmake сервера прописал:

```
# install to bin folder our binaries
install(TARGETS ${SERVER} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

# generate .deb package
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT scfocus@yandex.ru)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)

# include will generate proper code for .deb generation
include(CPack)
```

Весь проект нормально собирается и работает. Далее, я хочу командой

```
cmake --build . --target package
```

собрать сам пакет. Получаю ошибки:

> [100%] Built target unit_tests Run CPack packaging tool... CPack:
> Create package using STGZ CPack: Install projects CPack: - Run
> preinstall target for: AppChat CPack: - Install project: AppChat CMake
> Error at
> /home/travis/build/k-morozov/AppChat/build/lib/libbacktrace/cmake_install.cmake:79
> (file):   file INSTALL cannot find
> "/home/travis/build/k-morozov/AppChat/cmake/libbacktraceConfig.cmake".
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /home/travis/build/k-morozov/AppChat/build/cmake_install.cmake:47
> (include)
>
> CPack Error: Error when generating package: log4cplus Makefile:72:
> recipe for target 'package' failed make: *** [package] Error 1
> travis_time:end:07e93d08:start=1596029174281531721,finish=1596029177389895418,duration=3108363697,event=script
> [0K[31;1mThe command "cmake --build . --target package" exited with
> 2.[0m
>
> Done. Your build exited with 1.

Но backtrace и log4cplus - это сабмодули.
Чем можно исправить?
[ссылка на проект](https://github.com/k-morozov/AppChat/tree/deb_travis)

Comment: так а сервер зависит от этих сабмодулей? Если да, то, конечно, у вас ничего не соберется

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch я думал, что если бинарники собираются, то и deb пакет соберется. Не подскажите, что требуется сделать?

Comment: так а нужный бинарник-то собирается?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch конечно собирается. проблема именно с deb пакетом.

Comment: в таком случае попробуйте сформировать его другими средствами: например с помощью checkinstall